# Connection failed between Windows Servers

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I'm setting up an infrastructure based on Windows Server 2012. The firewall is turned off and I can't access the Domain controller to check for the group policy.

I'm experiencing some connection problem between servers. All the servers are running a site on the TCP Port 80 and I check with netstat that the web server is binding on every Ip of the servers.

If i try to telnet  from the server itself on the port 80 it works (using DNS name) if I try same telnet from another machine I get connection failed.

The DNS works, the ping is successfull, the servers are on the same subnet, the firewall is turned off (even though windows advanced firewall says that some settings can be managed by the System Administrator, i guess group policy).

I don't know how to troubleshoot further. Do you have any idea? Is that possible that the FW looks turned off but there are some group policy blocking the connections? (I also check group policy->Administrative Template->Network Connections-> Windows FW everything is not configured)

I need some hint on how to keep troubleshooting such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that there aren't two A-records in DNS for the DC you are trying to connect to. I had that issue when trying to connect to one of my servers via RDP and I was going bonkers. Make sure that the actual computer name of the DC is mapped to its IP address and that there are no other records for that DNS name referring to any other IP address.

Comment: nslookup gives me just one record. **Do you have any other command to check such an information?**

Answer (score 0):

In the windows firewall MMC check \monitoring\firewall to see current rules that are applied in case a gpo is overriding the local policy.

View the firewall log, the default location being:
%systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log

I would recommend installing Wireshark temporarily to be certain traffic is reaching the correct server. Wireshark will display any traffic prior to it hitting the windows firewall, if that is the issue.